# Elastic Beanstalk Procfile for go

Tags: amazon-web-services, go, deployment, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm trying to deploy my go restful server program to EC2 Linux using Elastic Beanstalk. The document says that I need to create a Procfile at the root. So I did. Here are the steps:

1. Build my go program myapp.go to using

   ```
   $ go build -o myapp -i myapp.go
   ```
2. Create a Procfile with exact name at the root with

   ```
   web: myapp
   ```
3. Zip up the Procfile and the myapp image to a `myapp.zip` file.

Upload to the server via Elastic Beanstalk console. But I keep getting `Degraded` health and warning with

> WARN   Process termination taking longer than 10 seconds.

Any suggestions. By the way, I tried to use the same procfile procedure on the simple `application.go` zip file came from the Elastic Beanstalk example library. It didn't work either.

Comment: Hi! I've got the same problem, did you solve it?

Comment: I have the same problem. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

I was finally able to get a Go application to deploy with Elastic Beanstalk using the [eb client](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/eb-cli3.html). There are a few things that EB requires:

1. The name of your main file should be `application.go`.
2. Make sure your app is listening on port 5000.
3. You'll need a Procfile in the main root with

   ```
   web: bin/application
   ```
4. You'll need a Buildfile with

   ```
   make: ./build.sh
   ```
5. And finally you'll need a `build.sh` file with

   ```
   #!/usr/bin/env bash
   # Stops the process if something fails
   set -xe

   # All of the dependencies needed/fetched for your project. 
   # FOR EXAMPLE:
   go get "github.com/gin-gonic/gin"

   # create the application binary that eb uses
   GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64 go build -o bin/application -ldflags="-s -w"
   ```

Then if you run `eb deploy` (after creating your initial eb repository), it should work. I wrote a whole tutorial for deploying a Gin application on EB [here](https://blog.memcachier.com/2018/07/30/gin-elastic-beanstalk-and-memcache/). The section specifically on deploying with Elastic Beanstalk is [here](https://blog.memcachier.com/2018/07/30/gin-elastic-beanstalk-and-memcache/#deploying-with-elastic-beanstalk).

Comment: Yikes, nice catch. Updated. Thanks!

Comment: None of this works for me, I don't get what's wrong. Same setup :(